# Single Task activity opening in same task?

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

I'm working on an application which responds to an intent from a third party application. The third party application uses an explicit intent to open our app's main activity.

When I put a breakpoint in our app main activity or run the adb shell dumpsys activity command, I see they use the intent flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**

Our activity uses the launch mode **android:launchMode="singleTask"**. You would expect our app to open in it's own task. However this is not the case.

These are the results I noticed

- Nexus 6, Android 6.0: Same task
- Samsung Galaxy Note 4, Android 5: Same task
- Samsung Galaxy s3, Android 4.4: New task
- Nexus 4, Android 4.4: New task

First question: Why is this the case? Based on the documentation, if the launch mode is **Single Task** AND the intent flag is **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**, for sure the new activity should open in it's own task.

This is what I get from dumpsys activity on the Nexus 6. I removed some names for privacy reasons.

```
Task id #280
  TaskRecord{a368235 #280 A=com.thirdPartyApp U=0 sz=4}
  Intent { flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.thirdPartyApp.Activity1 }
    Hist #3: ActivityRecord{2a95b00 u0 ca.myApp.Main t280}
      Intent { act=ca.myApp.Main.ACTION cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10000000 pkg=ca.myApp cmp=ca.myApp.Main bnds=[75,1648][1364,2937] (has extras) }
      ProcessRecord{df568e7 19422:ca.myApp/u0a277}
    Hist #2: ActivityRecord{d0c821b u0 com.thirdPartyApp.Activity3 t280}
      Intent { cmp=com.thirdPartyApp.Activity3 (has extras) }
      ProcessRecord{6779824 7717:com.thirdPartyApp/u0a15}
    Hist #1: ActivityRecord{26b0a9c u0 com.thirdPartyApp.Activity2 t280}
      Intent { act=com.thirdPartyApp.ACTION cmp=com.thirdPartyApp.Activity2 (has extras) }
      ProcessRecord{6779824 7717:com.thirdPartyApp/u0a15}
    Hist #0: ActivityRecord{3969feb u0 com.thirdPartyApp.Activity1 t280}
      Intent { flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.thirdPartyApp bnds=[114,434][1325,1645] }
      ProcessRecord{6779824 7717:com.thirdPartyApp/u0a15}
```

From the flag **flg=0x10000000** it's clear they are calling myApp with intent flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

It gets worse. If I return to home screen and launch myApp from home screen, it's opened twice in two separate tasks!

```
Task id #306
  TaskRecord{664c4c7 #306 A=ca.myApp U=0 sz=1}
  Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=ca.myApp.Main bnds=[113,378][337,602] (has extras) }
    Hist #0: ActivityRecord{88825a0 u0 ca.myApp.Main t306}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=ca.myApp.Main bnds=[113,378][337,602] (has extras) }
      ProcessRecord{df568e7 19422:ca.myApp.Main/u0a277}


Task id #280
  TaskRecord{a368235 #280 A=com.thirdPartyApp U=0 sz=4}
  Intent { flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.thirdPartyApp.Activity1 }
    Hist #3: ActivityRecord{2a95b00 u0 ca.myApp.Main t280}
      Intent { act=ca.myApp.Main.ACTION cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10000000 pkg=ca.myApp cmp=ca.myApp.Main bnds=[75,1648][1364,2937] (has extras) }
      ProcessRecord{df568e7 19422:ca.myApp/u0a277}
    Hist #2: ActivityRecord{d0c821b u0 com.thirdPartyApp.Activity3 t280}
      Intent { cmp=com.thirdPartyApp.Activity3 (has extras) }
      ProcessRecord{6779824 7717:com.thirdPartyApp/u0a15}
    Hist #1: ActivityRecord{26b0a9c u0 com.thirdPartyApp.Activity2 t280}
      Intent { act=com.thirdPartyApp.ACTION cmp=com.thirdPartyApp.Activity2 (has extras) }
      ProcessRecord{6779824 7717:com.thirdPartyApp/u0a15}
    Hist #0: ActivityRecord{3969feb u0 com.thirdPartyApp.Activity1 t280}
      Intent { flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.thirdPartyApp bnds=[114,434][1325,1645] }
      ProcessRecord{6779824 7717:com.thirdPartyApp/u0a15}
```

Second question: When I remove **android:launchMode="singleTask"** and retest on the s3 or the Nexus 4, myApp opens in the same task as third party app. From this document https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html it says the following

> If both activities define how Activity B should associate with a task,
>   then Activity A's request (as defined in the intent) is honored
>   over Activity B's request (as defined in its manifest).

From my tests its clear the Manifest attribute is honoured over the intent flags. Why is this the case?